# Imagick: Failed to read the file

Tags: php, symfony, imagick

I am using Sonata Media Bundle and Imagick in the hope of generating a preview image for a PDF. Ghostscript is installed. I try the following:

```
    $binaryContent = $media->getBinaryContent();
    $tempPdfFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'pdf');
    $tempJpegFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'jpeg');
    file_put_contents($tempPdfFile, $binaryContent);

    rename($tempPdfFile, $tempPdfFile . '.pdf');
    rename($tempJpegFile,$tempJpegFile . '.jpg');

    $im = new \Imagick($tempPdfFile . '.pdf');
    $im->setImageColorspace(255);
    $im->setResolution(72,72);
    $im->setCompressionQuality(75);
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $im->writeImage($tempJpegFile.'.jpg');
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
```

... but I get this error message:

> Failed to read the file

... on the line `$im = new \Imagick($tempPdfFile . '.pdf');`

**What am I doing wrong here?**

====

**Additional information:** I have also tried `$im = new \Imagick($tempPdfFile . '.pdf[0]');` with no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is roughly what worked in order to get me a useful reference to a file that Imagick can read.

```
public function preUpdate(Document $document)
{
    $media = $document->getMedia();
    if ($media === null) {
        return;
    }
    $mediaName = $media->getName();
    if ($media->getContentType() !== 'application/pdf') {
        return;
    }

    $context = $media->getContext();
    $formats = $pool->getFormatNamesByContext($context);

    if (null === $formats) {
        return;
    }

    $provider = $this->getProvider($media->getProviderName());
    $publicUrls = [];

    $fullFilePath = $provider->getReferenceImage($media);



}

...

private function getPool()
{
    return $this->container->get('sonata.media.pool');
}

...

private function getProvider($name)
{
    return $this->container->get($name);
}
```